# Prove cardinality of a function "f" = cardinality of the set "A"

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Let *A* be a finite set, and *B* be any set. Let *f* : A → B be a function.
Considering *f* as a set of ordered pairs, prove that |*f*| = |*A*|.**

I know logically that this is true, letting the set A = {1, 2, 3}, and B = $\mathbb{Z}$. Then *f* = {(1, x), (2, y), (3, z)}, for some x, y, z ${\in}$ $\mathbb{Z}$.

But what is the correct way to going about a formal proof?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Suppose $$A = \{ a_i |i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}\}$$ where $a_i \neq a_j$.

Let $f(a_i)=b_i$, then we can write

$$f = \{ (a_i, b_i)|i \in (1, \ldots, n\}.$$

Check that $g:A \to f$ where $g(a_i)=(a_i,b_i)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Exercise:  prove the cardinality of any function equals the cardinality of its domain no matter what the size of the domain.